# How to access Key Vault without connectiong to Azure

Tags: powershell

I need to automate a task and I'm going to store some variables and secrets that I need for future scripts.
Is there a way that to access my key vault without using the command Connect-AzConnect, and without using a specific user to do so?

Right now I'm using the command `Get-AzKeyVaultSecret`, I've noticed the argument `-DefaultProfile`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, but do you have an example that I could follow? I've never worked with managed identities. Thank you

Comment: Could you explain your use case in some more detail? Want to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve before talking about a solution.

- Automate a task - Are you running this task from Azure Pipeline? Github Actions? What is the runtime for the task? Is it going to run in a VM? a container ? as part of a pipeline task?  

Also why is Connect-AzConnect not an option?

The more details you can give us the better solution we could suggest.